# Predict background counts given past observations and assumption of linear variation of the rate parameter in time

Tags: regression, likelihood, stochastic-processes, poisson-process, point-process

Consider the following problem. We have a time series of counts (poisson-distributed) data. In this time series we can select an *off-pulse* window in which only background is present and a subsequent *on-pulse* window in which a source signal may or may not be present.

I want to estimate a mean value and error for the background counts in the on-pulse window $b = b \pm \sigma$, given the off pulse observations and the assumptions that the poisson rate can change linearly $\sim mt + q$.

The actual situation is depicted in the following picture. A paper I'm studying claims that $b$ should be normally distributed with good approximation, even when $b$ is small.

This looks as a fairly straightforward problem which I don't how know to approach. If data were gaussian distributed and error bars were given, a linear regression would do the trick. In particular, i would estimate $m \pm \sigma_m$ and $q \pm \sigma_q$ and propagate their errors.

Where should I look?

One remark: i'm particularly interested in the case in which on-pulse window is small (few counts).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have a Poisson point process with intensity (rate) function $\lambda(t)$, say. Assume the observation window is contained in the interval $[0, T]$ and the observed points $t_1, t_2, \dotsc, t_n$.  Let $N(T)$ be the total count of points. Then we can show that
$$ N(T) \sim \mathcal{Poisson}\left( \int_0^T \lambda(t)\; dt \right) $$
and there is the following **Theorem**: (See Pawitan, *In All Likelihood* (reference in here: [Manipulating Binomial Distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58594/manipulating-binomial-distribution/453747#453747))):  Given $N(T)=n$, the times $t_1, t_2, \dotsc, t_n$ are distributed as the order statistics of an iid sample from a distribution with density proportional to $\lambda(t)$. Introducing $\Lambda(T)=\int_0^T \lambda(t)\; dt$ this density is
$$\frac{\lambda(t)}{\Lambda(T)} $$
Denoting by $\theta$ unknown parameters in the intensity function, we can now find the likelihood function for $\theta$:
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
L(\theta)= \P\left(N(T)=n\right)\cdot \P(t_1, t_2, \dotsc, t_n | N(T)=n) \\
   = e^{-\Lambda(T)} \frac{\Lambda(T)^n}{n!}\times n! \prod_1^n \frac{\lambda(t_i)}{\Lambda(T)} \\
= e^{-\Lambda(T)} \prod_1^n \lambda(t_i)
$$ and using your assumption on the intensity function and the two windows, you can take it from here, using maximum likelihood estimation.

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks like what I was looking for! I will now try to work with paper. Will be back to you. I have one question for the moment: how does the likelihood not depend on the observed counts $n_i$ or the total number of counts $ \sum n_i $ but the time $t_i$ of the observations?  is there something I am missing?